# Managing multiple platforms for one game in Unity

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine

**TL;DR:** My game should be different on PC and phone, can i manage these different version without just making multiple unity projects ?

Hello,

I am creating a game but i want some features to be different depending on the platform, i want it to be avaible from mobile but also from PC. But i have some differences:

- **UI**: on PC, the inventory and the shop should be always visible, on phone i want two buttons to open them, with of course lot of other differences in elements size, position...
- **Ads**: i want the phone version of my game to have a banner ad on the bottom on the screen
- **Gameplay mechanics**: i want on the phone version to have multiple event that randomly spawn, which grants bonuses (currency, boosters...) to the player after he watch an ad, i can only display ads on mobile so the events should only be avaible on mobile.
- **Real currency**: i want a real currency shop, but i think it's coded differently on computer and mobile.

What's the best option for me now ?

- Create the base game, then clone the folder and the repository so i have one for PC, one for mobile, and then implement the platform related features separately.
- Same as above, but instead of different git repositories, git subrepositories.
- Multiple git branches.
- Something else ??

The problem with the two first methods is that if i want to implement a new feature that is not platform related, i need to code it on a project and then copy it into another, is there a better way for doing this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well .. the entire idea of Unity is that you can build to different platforms ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to manage different versions of your game for PC and mobile platforms within the same Unity project. You can use #if UNITY_EDITOR, #if UNITY_STANDALONE, #if UNITY_ANDROID, #if UNITY_IOS, etc., to conditionally compile code for different platforms. Have a look at [Platform Dependent Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) in the Unity documentation.

Comment: But how can i make for UI to have elements sized and anchored differently depending on platform ?

Comment: You can create adaptive UIs that scale and anchor differently based on the platform by using the Unity UI system, @draymone. You can also adjust UI elements programmatically based on the current screen size or resolution. Use scripts to detect the platform and adjust the RectTransform properties.